# How do I make my model smooth?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to do a 3d model of a rabbit but it looks more like a balloon. I have tried adding more poly's and I have tried sculping but neither seem to work.[image: balloon looking rabbit]

Comment: Right click > shade smooth

Comment: Select ur mesh object and in the object mode click smooth on the tool bar...

Comment: Use fewer verts.

Comment: i've tried all of those and it doesn't seem to fix it im going to try adding polys over it

Comment: Can you upload an image of the wireframe for this model? I think you have some weird geometry going on. Also upload the .blend file so others can take a look in more detail. I'm sure I can solve your problem if you just provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things you could try:

- select the vertices you want to smooth, right click, select "Smooth Vertices"
- apply the subdivision modifier -> this will make the model have more faces

  - For more reading here is the  Blender Subdivision Modifier Manual
- You could shade smooth, in order to do this:
  - Go to Object data properties > Normals > check the box and select the degree of angle you would like to be auto smoothed
  - select the model and go to mesh > normals > recalculate outside
  - finally, go to mesh > shading > smooth faces

I hope one of these helps, good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I mirrored the object so there was 2 bunny heads instead of 1.